# Can "window" and "time span" be used interchangeably?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

According to the web version of the Merriam-Webster dictionary, "window" can mean the following:

> an interval of time during which certain conditions or an opportunity exists

So can I say "a window of leisure" instead of "a time span of leisure"? Being leisure surly seems to be "certain condition", although the former reads odd and the word seems hardly to be used in this way.

More importantly, **is there any situation** that "window" and "time span" shouldn't be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and no.

While the dictionary gives a definition, it doesn't include all the details of idiomatic use. There are expressions like "window of opportunity" and "a window in my schedule"... but not "window of leisure".  So "no" this expression isn't idiomatic.

And "time span" doesn't contain the meaning of "while certain conditions exist".  So "no" window and time span aren't interchangeable. Indeed it is hard to think of an example of a sentence in which "time-span" and "window" *are* interchangable.